# Elasticsearch Unable to print array in PHP

Tags: php, arrays, elasticsearch, composer-php

I followed this [Video](https://youtu.be/3xb1dHLg-Lk?t=4m12s) as a guide to get elasticsearch up and running with PHP, but I am unable to print or view the results. I can print the raw data, but i'm unable to go any deeper.

- Operating system: Debian (jessie)
- PHP version: 5.6.30
- Java version: 1.7.0
- Elasticsearch version: 5.4.0

I use this code to request the data:

```
// Creating the request.
if(!defined('JSON_PRESERVE_ZERO_FRACTION'))
{
    define('JSON_PRESERVE_ZERO_FRACTION', 1024);
}

require_once('vendor/autoload.php'); // autoload which makes it "easier"
                                     // to get values from elasticsearch
$hosts = [
    "192.168.1.120:9200"
];
$client = Elasticsearch\ClientBuilder::create()
    ->setHosts($hosts)
    ->build();

// Define the search
$query = ([
    'index' => '*',
    'type' => '*',
    'body' => [
            'from' => 0,
        'size' => 40,
        'query' => [
            'query_string' => [
                    'query' => 'a'
            ]
        ]
    ]
]);
$raw = $client->search($query);

print_r($raw);
```

This print_r($raw); returns this:

```
Array ( [took] => 2 [timed_out] => [_shards] => Array ( [total] => 30 [successful] => 30 [failed] => 0 ) [hits] => Array ( [total] => 0 [max_score] => [hits] => Array ( ) ) )
```

I know that by doing print_r, it should show all arrays inside eachother. So I don't understand what I'm doing wrong here? I know it should be displaying because I did the same thing in program called POSTMAN, and got back 40 results. I also tried another PHP version. PHP7, but it returned the same thing.

What am I doing wrong here?

Comment: Because hits=>hits is empty?  There's not any depth to plumb?  It almost looks as if you're searching for "a" ... have you tried a longer term not likely to be in a stopwords file/db?

Comment: I tried removing the whole query, query_string, query, a which should give me results of everything, but still got the same result

Comment: Why *remove* it?  What's your index like?  Try a search for "without", or "long", or "cookie", or "house", or "donut".  Don't try "a", "an", "the" ... those are stopwords in most search systems.  Removing the query shouldn't cause you to get results ... unless you're reading the docs and it says so ... and that seems counter-intuitive.

Comment: Searching "house" outputtet the same result. Yes the database contains over 600 000 documents. However, using POSTMAN gave me 2436 results on searching "house".

Comment: I can try using curl instead of the composer, and see if I can come any closer.

Comment: Hmm, I wonder ... if you can't get it with one UA the other may not make any difference.  Are you sure your index for Elasticsearch has content?  Or does your POSTMAN use the same index?

Comment: Postman is written a little bit different. Like this:
`{
 "from":0,"size":40,
 "query":{
  "query_string":{
   "query":"house"
  }
 }
}`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It seems like it didn't like that I put * as index and type. So to either remove them, or change them to a working index,type will fix the problem.
For anyone else having this problem, this is the basic fix:

```
$query = [
    'body' => [
        'query' => [
            'match' => [
                'title' => 'Your search'
            ]
        ]
    ]
];
```

or

```
$query = [
    'index' => 'your valid index',
    'type' => 'your valid type',
    'body' => [
        'query' => [
            'match' => [
                'title' => 'Your search'
            ]
        ]
    ]
];
```